# How to alter the title of a views exposed form block with code

Tags: views, blocks

The title says it all really. My views exposed form block has no title but I want to add one through code. I have been looking through the api for hours and am totally lost. I have tried tons of things but my drupal and php chops are limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function hook_block_view_alter(&$data, $block) {
  if ($block->bid == $id) {
    $block->title = $title;
  }
}
```

Where `hook` is the name of your module, `$id` is the numeric ID of the block and `$title` is the desired title.

You can find the ID with the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module by putting `dpm($block);` inside the `hook_block_view_alter()` function and then looking at the output for each block to see which one matches. It'll have a `delta` attribute on the `$block` object something like `-exp-your_view_name-display` where `your_view_name` is obviously the name of the view, and `display` is the type of display, e.g. page or block. Or you can just pattern-match the `delta` value instead of selecting by ID, up to you.

Comment: So I placed the block as a display suite "block field", and am not seeing it as a block in the dpm output. Would this type of block need special handling?

Comment: Do you see the structure of any blocks from the `dpm()` at all?

Comment: There are two dozen blocks in the `dpm()` output, but not the one I created through display suite. I played with your code for a bit but ended up just adding the the title through the ui.

Comment: I don't have a lot of Display Suite experience but I think it's very different than core blocks.