# How to use hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter on Views-exposed form?

Tags: hooks, blocks

I want to use [`hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter/7) to modify a Views-exposed form. The URL path to the configuration page for the block is:

```
admin/structure/block/manage/views/-exp-resources_by_subject-page/configure
```

As you can see, it's delta value is `-exp-resources_by_subject-page`, which means my `hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter` now becomes:

```
function mymodule_block_view_views_-exp-resources_by_subject-page_alter(&$data, $block) {}
```

This, of course, returns an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting '('
```

I don't want to use [`hook_block_view_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7) as mentioned [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/79819/18794) because, as that is called for all blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue with block module and may be you get your answer here. Please check the url

https://www.drupal.org/node/1076132
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter/7